# why does the order of variable declaring matter?

Tags: c

I'm fairly new to C and I have a small function which reads an input of a simple math operation (+,-,*,/) and then calculates the result accordingly and returns -nan if the input is incorrect.

```
float simple_math(void) {
float a, b;
int char_c;
int ret_a;


ret_a = scanf("%f %c %f", &a, &char_c, &b);
float result;

if (char_c == '+')
    result = a + b;
else if (char_c == '-')
    result = a - b;
else if (char_c == '*')
    result = a * b;
else if (char_c == '/')
    result = a / b;
else
    result = 0.0 / 0.0;

return result;
}
```

This code works just fine. However, if I change the order of the first two lines the return value is -nan.

```
int char_c;
float a, b;   // this was originally the first line
int ret_a;
```

Why does the order of the variable declarations matter?

Comment: `result = 0.0 / 0.0;` - WTF?

Comment: @szczurcio He uses that to return `NaN` if none of the operations match.

Comment: Both ways work fine for me with gcc on linux.

Comment: It's nice that you save the return value of `scanf()`, less nice that you then ignore it. You need to check that it's `3` before relying on the target variables having well-defined values.

Comment: It matters because it's a 99.9% certain touchstone for UB.

Comment: It is mostly a good idea to initialise all variables. It is always when debugging.

Comment: Some basic debugging would likely show you that `char_c` has the wrong value, which would point you at the problem.

Comment: ^^ what @interjay says.  People developing software with no debugger.. :((

Comment: @alk in this case, initialising the var may have just covered up the problem.

Comment: I guess this question is pretty much answered already. Just the last thing on my mind was, why did 'order' matter on this occasion. Nidhoegger's comment about a char being smaller than an int struck a chord with me. I tried this example in linux-gcc, and I got nan results for both permutations. I did manage to make it work (with int char_c) with both permutations by initialising the var (int char_c = 0;). So for lagi (and his compiler) perhaps that hints at that it worked one way due to the char_c getting allocated to a memory location that was nicely zeroed (by chance)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
int char_c;
```

should be

```
char char_c;
```

`%c` is used to scan character and not `int` so your scanf will lead to undefined behavior.

The side effect of undefined behavior is sometimes things work as expected. So please get rid of undefined behavior it has nothing to do with the ordering of variable definitions.

Comment: When you invoke undefined behavior, anything is possible, and it's often sensitive to things that shouldn't ordinarily matter, because it changes the memory layout.

Comment: Still, the answer should be: order of variables doesn't matter, following by explanation why it doesn't and how's the expected behavior possible :) And, no, I'm not the downvoter neither.

Comment: @zubergu I disagree please read my full answer where I say ordering doesn't matter .

Comment: But you should not get undefined behaviour here. As an `int` normally is bigger then a `char`, you dont overwrite memory by reading a `char` to an `int`. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Gopi That's what you get for posting crappy answer just to be the first and the edit it to actually answer the original question. Confusion and downvotes.

Comment: @zubergu Sir with all respect SO allows you to edit the answers and I didn't answer just to be first. The issue here was with the scanf() and pointed it out first later added more details which any SO user will agree with

Comment: @Gopi Yeah, especially those users who read your original answer and decided to downvote whatever they saw. I'm not going to get into this discussion, not the place not the time. Learn to deal with possibility of people not liking that attitude to giving answers. That's all. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 5):

This is your problem:

```
int char_c;

ret_a = scanf("%f %c %f", &a, &char_c, &b);
```

You tell `scanf` here to read a `char`, but pass him an `int` instead. That causes `scanf` to read only the size of a char (1byte) instead of the size of an `int` (larger than bytes), so in the end, whats contained in `char_c` is random and definitiveley non of the four allowed characters (`x-*/`).